# Why is my kafka topic not being reset to 0?

Tags: apache-kafka

When I describe one of my topics I get this status:

```
➜  local-kafka_2.12-2.0.0 bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server myip:1025 --group mygroup --describe
Consumer group 'mygroup' has no active members.

TOPIC           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID     HOST            CLIENT-ID
mytopic         0          858             858             0               -               -               -
```

when I try to reset it to the earliest, I get this status:

```
➜  local-kafka_2.12-2.0.0 bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server myip:1025 --group mygroup --topic mytopic --reset-offsets --to-earliest --execute

TOPIC                          PARTITION  NEW-OFFSET
mytopic                        0          494
```

I would have expected the new offset to be at `0` rather than `494`.

**Question**

1 - In the `describe` output the current offset is shown as `858`, however resetting to earliest shows as `494`. So there would be a lag of `364`. My question is, what happened to the remaining `494` (`858-364`) offsets? Are they gone because of some configuration setup for this topic? My `retention.ms` is set to 1 week
2 - If the `494` records are gone, is there a way to recover them somehow?

Comment: Is your topic log compacted?

Comment: Those records are deleted as per your retention policy.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have access to the data directory of your kafka clusters, you can see the data that is present in there using the command `kafka-run-class.bat kafka.tools.DumpLogSegments`.

For more information see e.g. here: https://medium.com/@durgaswaroop/a-practical-introduction-to-kafka-storage-internals-d5b544f6925f

Your data might have been deleted either due to log retention time or due to size limitation of the logs (the configuration property `log.retention.bytes`).